# Format number with space as thousand separator. It's important to keep the initial number of decimals

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Would you help me, please, to convert a string with format either '99999.999' else '99999' into another string with thousands separated by spaces:
'99 999.999'
'99 999'
It's important to keep the initial number of decimals. That is, if the string has 3 decimals after the point, we should keep them all. If the string has 1 desimal after the point, we should keep 1.

I try to apply:

```
declare @num varchar(40) = '99999999999999.1254'
declare @str_dec varchar(3) = (case when @num like '%[.,]%' then '.00' else '' end)

select format(convert(decimal(30,6), @num),'### ### ### ### ### ##0' + @str_dec)
```

But this doesn't accept the number of decimals more than 2. That is, if to change '.00' to '.0000' the number of decimals will be 2 anyway.

It it related to the other method the adding the spaces. E.g.

```
replace(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST('99999999999999.1254'  AS money) ,1)  ,',',' '), '.', ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, format function accepts more digits than 2. The problem was because of the variable @str_dec datatype varchar(3), which restricted the number of digits.

Full code:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_split_thousands_in_number] ( @num varchar(40) )
returns varchar(40)
begin

declare @structure varchar(40) = '### ### ### ### ### ##0'; --out structure
declare @str_len int = len(@num); --len symbols in a number
declare @index_place int = charindex('.', @num); --place of point in a number
declare @digits_after_point int = @str_len - @index_place; --len symbols in a number after point
declare @digits_to_point int = @index_place - 1; --len symbols in a number to point
declare @num_spaces_to_ins int = @digits_to_point / 3; --num thousands in a number
declare @structure_after_cut varchar(40)  = right(@structure, @digits_to_point + @num_spaces_to_ins) --structure for out after cut. If not to do, the unuseful spaces will be added
declare @str_dec varchar(10) = (case when @num like '%.%' then '.' + REPLICATE ( '0' , @digits_after_point )  else '' end) --number of decimals to out

  return ltrim(format(convert(decimal(30,6), @num),@structure_after_cut + @str_dec));
end;
```